# Passing a map to a function that specifies a map argument with unbounded wild cards

Tags: java, generics

I am basically trying to do a check of a `Map` in Java. My code is as follows.

```
private boolean isValid(Map<?,?> map) {
 return (null != map && map.size() > 0);
}
```

Why can't I use this method as follows?

```
Map<String, String> m = new HashMap<>();
isValid(m);
```

In Eclipse, I get the following error message:

`The method isValid(Map<?,?>) in the type MyClazz is not applicable for the arguments (Map<String,String>)`

As I am writing this question, I tried the following and it "works".

```
isValid( (Map<?,?>) m);
```

Why is this? Thumbing through the SO posts, I got a "similar" problem stating the problem of wildcard capture. But it doesn't seem like that's the problem here (without casting).

Comment: Which Eclipse version you using? This should compile (although not very good code), and it does compile with Eclipse Mars 4.5.1 (just tested).

Comment: why not isValid(Map map) instead?

Comment: @Leo:  That'd be working with raw types, and raw types are bad.

Comment: This works completely fine for me.

Comment: Are you using an older version of the Eclipse compiler?

Comment: i'm on Eclipse `Version: Mars.1 Release (4.5.1), Build id: 20150924-1200` with JavaSE-1.8 set on the build path and compiler compliance level set to 1.8.

Comment: Are some of you saying that this is not a Java issue per say, but one with Eclipse?

Comment: @Makoto the function isValid() that Jane is using does not need this information. It just tests if the Map is empty

Comment: @Leo:  This is why the wildcards are being used.  If you can at all avoid using raw types, you should.

Comment: learning something new everyday. thanks @Makoto -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it

Answer (score 0):

This error does not occur with the example you've provided in either Java 8's `javac` or Eclipse Mars. You might try refreshing your project or cleaning the project (Project > Clean...), but otherwise your example does not replicate your actual problem.

One possibility is you're importing some other `Map` than `java.util.Map`.

This example compiles without issue, both with `javac` and Eclipse.

```
$ cat Demo.java 
import java.util.*;

class Demo {
  // isEmpty() is a better way to check if a Map is empty rather
  // than .size() > 0, which is O(n) for some Map implementations.
  public static boolean nonEmpty(Map<?,?> map) {
    return map != null && !map.isEmpty();
  }

  public static boolean nonZero(Map<?,?> map) {
    return null != map && map.size() > 0;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    nonEmpty(new HashMap<String, String>());
    nonZero(new HashMap<String, String>());
  }
}

$ javac Demo.java; echo $?
0
```